# fancyhead gradient doesn't match bg colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I have a "fading line" from white to grey in my header. I wanted to add a page with a different background colour, and therefore fade from this colour instead of white. The problem is that the start of the gradient doesn't match the colour of the page... Any ideas? Complete code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm, showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bgsummary}{cmyk}{0.2,0,0.1,0}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\ifodd\count0\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\else\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=black, right color=white, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\fi}

\fancypagestyle{summary}{%
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize\textcolor{grey}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\normalsize\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\ifodd\count0\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=bgsummary, right color=darkgrey, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\else\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=darkgrey, right color=bgsummary, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\fi}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter with a long title}
\lipsum

\newpage
\thispagestyle{summary}
\section{Summary}
\pagecolor{bgsummary}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `xcolor` package option `cmyk` the `xcolor` package will convert all colors to the `cmyk` model. Nevertheless `shade` will use `rgb` colors. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,
rgb, % this option is passed to xcolor
%cmyk % this option is passed to xcolor
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{bgsummary}{cmyk}{0.2,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{bgsummary}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[fill=bgsummary](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\tikz\draw[shade,left color=bgsummary,right color=bgsummary](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\end{document}
```

Result with option `rgb`

[image]

Result with option `cmyk`

[image]

But you can load the `fadings` library and use `path fading`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright,
  cmyk% this option is passed to xcolor
]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm,
  paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm,
  layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm,
  layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm,
  showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\definecolor{bgsummary}{cmyk}{0.2,0,0.1,0}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}%
  \leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}%
  \thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\ifodd\count0\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (5.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\else\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (5.98,.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\fi}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter with a long title}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\pagecolor{bgsummary}
\section{Summary}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used `5.98` instead `4.98` as width of the headrule rectangle and that the summary page also gets the pagestyle `fancy`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are defining the new background color using CMYK model and using RGB model for the gradient.

Use

```
\definecolor{bgsummary}{rgb}{0.8,1,0.9}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Is it possible to do it the other way around? I tried changing the grey colours to cmyk, but it wasn't enough... Is tikz RGB based, or can I use cmyk instead?

Comment: It is better to don't mix colour models. You can convert between them. http://web.forret.com/tools/color.asp Since it is not a good idea to print a pdf file with coloured BG, I suggest you to use RGB model, it works well for screens.

Comment: This is for a book, so it will be printed. The coloured bg is only for a summary page at the end of each chapter. All the content will therefore be printed using cmyk.

Comment: So read the Tikz user guide and xcolor also to use cmyk as a model.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

`tikz` now supports CMYK shadings since version 3.1.3. Just load `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option before loading `tikz`.

---

The other answers explain why you get this problem well.

There is a new solution to this problem using the `pgf-cmykshadings` package which supports CMYK shadings in `pgf`. Change the start of your document to:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}% always use CMYK
\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}% use CMYK in PGF shadings
```

You need to load `pgf-cmykshadings` before `tikz` to ensure you get CMYK shadings everywhere. I'd also load `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option in your case and maybe define your grey colours in `cmyk` too.

```
\definecolor{grey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.6}
```

Now the colours will match and you'll get a document in CMYK suitable for printing.

[image]