# Fancy header and footer in Latex?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

How can I change the style of my header/footer from something like this :

[image]

I want to replace that line with the following line :

[image]

It doesn't actually matter the colour as long as we will have a gradient on a specific colour, I actually want the same style for the footer, Thanks you everybody

Comment: Related **(1)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334629/ **(2)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127052 **(3)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519173

Comment: more... **(4)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69950

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks you, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick 'n' dirty example based on [fancyhead gradient doesn't match bg colour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241738). To be honest, I do not fully understand the code. `0.01` is the thickness  (in cm) on the headrule and `14.98` is the length (in cm).

The **important part** is that you can re-define `fancyhdr`'s `\headrule`
command with some `tikz` magic.

At least, you can use the code as a basis for your own experiments and as a basis for a potential follow-up question (see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tikz}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241738
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=white, right color=blue, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (14.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks you, I really appreciate it

Comment: Another question please, Is there any way  that we can centre that line right in the middle of the paper cause I thinks it's a little bit heeded to the right ? Thanks you

Comment: @THEWOLFSNOW Hi. I am busy this week (work!) and I probably won't be able to help until the weekend.

Comment: Thanks you, I already figure it out Thanks you so much for the help I really appreciate it

Comment: @THEWOLFSNOW You can provide your solution as a separate answer so that others can learn from it. Or you can accept/upvote my answer to indicate that it helped you.

Comment: Actually your answer is the correct one, if someone want to centre that line he just have to change the value of `rectangle (14.98,0.01)` to `(17.6,0.05)` for headers and `(19.5,0.05)` for footers, so basically your code is so perfect so Thanks you